# Is the UITableViewCell subclass used in Apple's native Mail app available anywhere online?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, email, subclass

Is the UITableViewCell subclass used in Apple's native Mail app available anywhere online?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is. But that is simple to do with IB. You can open your IB, drag in a new UITableViewCell and then customize it, link it back to the class code. Here is another [Blog post](http://www.bdunagan.com/2009/06/28/custom-uitableviewcell-from-a-xib-in-interface-builder/) that shows you how to do it and how to link it back to your class code

Answer (score 1):

Certainly not from Apple. Custom `UITableViewCell` classes are actually relatively simple to put together, and the one in Mail is not especially complex. [Here's a great blog post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) on customizing these cells.

Comment: It looks a little bit complex for the beginners I guess

Comment: It's actually complex when you consider the left to right swipe gesture. As far as I can tell, right to left is native and well documented but not for left to right...

Comment: @Atticus Indeed it is significantly more complex now than it was when this question was asked. :)